# Editor cound not be initialized - Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, layout

I am not able to open any layout file in Eclipse IDE.
Getting error message as

[image]

And after that the file seems as below:

[image]

Comment: See if there is a more detailed message in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem solved by Exiting from Eclipse IDE, Clearing all the Tasks from Task Manager and finally Restarting my PC.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall Eclipse, this is the only way i resolved the issue. I know its a long process. Maybe try repair it first then restarting your pc.